# Java socket read method returns -1

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I'm writing server side application which handle incoming request from Flash over RTMP. On the server side I've got simple blocking IO.

I noticed that over 10-30 % sessions are terminated when `InputStream.read` returns -1, which should indicate end of stream. These requests are terminated at the very beginning of user sessions, so I don't really think users close their browser...

Less often `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` exception occurs on attempt to write to the stream.

It's look rather suspicious, that I receive end of the steam so many time. What could be the reason of receiving `end of stream` at the very beginning of conversation ?

Comment: Does the client send something immediately when it opens the socket?

Comment: Yes, there is a handshake procedure. During handshake client and server exchange some data. Usually EOF occurs after handshake passed.

Comment: Could the client crash in the calculation of what to send for the handshake? That would explain what you are seeing...

Comment: I don't really think so. Sometimes client managed to send few more commands before EOF occurs.

Comment: Is there a bad or unreliable link? Broken switch or cable ... "Powerline" ... whatever?

Comment: A client can disconnect or timeout or retry before the connection has started. e.g. say a client clicks a link twice, this creates and cancels the first request and creates a second request.

Comment: @PeterLawrey good point, but not my case. I can see now some patterns, when EOF occurs. Looks like server indeed kills the client with bad ACK of bytes read. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The client has closed the connection, from your point of view prematurely. This explains both the -1 and the 'broken pipe'. Just accept it and deal with it. In general a peer should be able to exit the conversation at any step.